# Why can't I use ChatPromptTemplate instead of PromptTemplate while creating a router prompt on MultiPromptChain?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I am new to Langchain and I was recently learning about Multi Route Chain. While practising it on my own, I was wondering why can't we use ChatPromptTemplate instead of PromptTemplate to get the router prompt.

```
Router_temp = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(destinations = destination_str)
router_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate(template = Router_temp, input_variables=["input"], output_parser= RouterOutputParser())
router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm =llm, prompt = router_prompt)
```

The following is the error it throws:
KeyError: 'messages'

But when I used ChatPromptTemplate previously in my code for a similar situation, it worked. As you can see below:

```
beginner_phy_teach = """You are a Physics teacher who specialises in basic physics concepts. Your name is Feynman, always introduce yourself. Explain these concepts like your audience are five
The topic is as follows\n. {input}"""

advanced_phy_teach = """You are a Physics teacher who specialises in advanced physics concepts. Your name is Oppenheimer, always introduce yourself. Explain these concepts like your audience already know the basics.
The topic is as follows\n. {input}"""

prompt_info = [{"Name": "Beginner Physics Teacher", "Description": "Good for answering questions related to beginner Physics concepts", "Template": beginner_phy_teach
}, {"Name": "Advanced Physics Teacher", "Description": "Good for answering questions related to advanced Physics concepts", "Template": advanced_phy_teach
}]

destination_chains = {}
for p in prompt_info:
    name = p["Name"]
    template = p["Template"]
    chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=template)
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=chat_prompt)
    destination_chains[name] = chain
```